# Error message Multi Part Identifier could not be bound

Tags: validation, t-sql

I am writing a SQL query to use in a Boyum validation that will flag and BP Master Data NAMES that are LIKE

Here is the query I have written

```
    IF OCRD.Cardname IN (Select OCRD.Cardname from OCRD WHERE OCRD.Cardname 
    LIKE '%'+Cardname+'%')
    BEGIN 
    SELECT 'Duplicate' 
    FOR BROWSE
    END
```

Here is the error message I have received

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "OCRD.Cardname" could not be bound.
2). [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
)

Comment: `IF OCRD.Cardname` exists outside any `select` (or other) statement, so there is no context for referencing the column. The query will resolve `Cardname` in the `like` expression to `OCRD.Cardname` and will always match (Itself!) as long as there is at least one row where the column is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

That is invalid SQL you provided. You can't reference a table column like that

```
IF EXISTS (Select OCRD.Cardname from OCRD WHERE OCRD.Cardname LIKE '%'+Cardname+'%')
    BEGIN 
    SELECT 'Duplicate' 
    FOR BROWSE
    END
```